# How to catch messageBack in node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to use messageBack in Bot framework. (The reason is postBack is not supported for MS Teams and imBack shows the system message to the user. I also tried to use invoke but that function is no longer in the botbuilder library)
I found the function messageBack in the library botbuilder, but I dont know how to catch the action once user presses the button.

For imBack I can use this:

```
bot.dialog('catchOption', [
    function (session, args, next) {
    }
]).triggerAction({ matches: /choose-time-card[0-9]+-[0-9]+/i});
```

I tried invoke but this is said to be limited to "internal use" whatever that means. So I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
bot.on('invoke', function (event) {
    var msg = new builder.Message().address(event.address);
    msg.data.text = "I see that you clicked a button.";
    bot.send(msg);
    bot.send(JSON.stringify(event));
});
```

Does anyone know?

Comment: Since the question's been put on hold, I can't answer it, but the documentation for how to use messageBack in Teams is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-cards - search for "messageBack" on the page. There's a source code example here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/blob/544e0fedcc1ae5c7e571e80102786384e18f7001/src/dialogs/examples/basic/HeroCardDialog.ts

Answer (score 0):

A few comments on this:

The SDK release from a few days ago 3.14 reinstated the `Invoke` ActionType.

To accomplish what you want to do it is as simple as something like this:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function(session) {
    if(session.message.text === "your messageback value"){
        //do stuff
    }else{
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
    }
}).set('storage', inMemoryStorage);
```

Comment: This doesnt work for MS Teams and in other channels the messageBack doesnt generate any message.
When I press the button the card shows up again and the action is not caught.
Maybe you could suggest how to catch invoke?